# VueJS Stack Traces Do Not Show Where Errors Occur

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, source-maps

### Context

[Source Code](https://github.com/Noah-Huppert/gh-gantt/tree/b69c21168b4cfba9f6ad5e95999afc2f3efa5134/frontend)

I am using VueJS with webpack in a project.

I am not using the `vue-loader` plugin or `.vue` files.

My project is structured like a standard Javascript webpack project which imports `vue`.

My webpack configuration has the following relevant options:

- `dev-tool: "source-map"`
- `resolve.alias["vue$"] = "vue/dist/vue.js"`

Source maps for my webpack Javascript bundle file are being generated.

### Issue

While programming an error showed up in the console. Unfortunately the stack trace shows the error as being in the `vue.js` file and later the webpack generated Javascript bundle file (`main.js`).

[image: Vue Error]

It looks like the source map generated for my Javascript bundle by webpack is not working properly.

I found [several](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/620) [related](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/1163) [issues](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/46524), however these issues seem to be related to the `vue-loader` webpack plugin which I do not use.

Looking at the application source in Firefox I can confirm that source maps are not functioning correctly:

[image: Source Maps Not Working In Firefox Source View]

The same behavior occurs in Chrome.

What could be causing source maps to not work correctly?

*Note: The error shown in the screenshots is not the focus, I was able to figure it out. The main focus of the question is that source maps are not working correctly. Making it harder to debug issues when they do appear.*

Comment: Have you tried https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/imgs/source-maps.jpg

Comment: @StarkButtowski not my question but I did follow it. Yes, JS sourcemaps are enabled. I do get some explanation, but it's buried, and really not that explanatory.

Answer (score 6):

If you're debugging in Chrome and sourcemaps are not working you have a few alternative options. This may not be as helpful as getting sourcemaps working, but your question has gone unanswered for a year and a half, so perhaps this will be useful.

[image: Sources Options]

One of my favorites is to use the "Pause on Exceptions" toggle in the Sources tab. In the picture above it's the octogon with a pause icon. Click on that and refresh your page. When the error occurs your application will pause with the error in a full stack trace, like so:

[image: Stack Trace Example]

That Call Stack is clickable. You can move backward through calling functions until you see something identifiable from your own source. If source maps are not loading properly I'd recommend looking for string literals. Those won't be minified in the output and can point you back to where the error is being triggered.

---

Also, you may want to consider using a Vue plugin like [Vue.js DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd). I find this sort of data-centric view of the application quite helpful. You can watch state and mutations and even replay or modify actions happening in your app to pinpoint errors.

Comment: Thank you very much. These are great techniques for tracking down errors without source maps.